# Preparing time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, data-manipulation

I have a data file of rainfall saved in .txt format as

```
Year   1,   2,   3,   4,   ................365, 366
1981   1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ................1.2, 0.0
1982   0.8, 0.0, 4.5, 2.3,.................0.9, 2.1
.
.
.
.

2015  0.0, 2.3, 8.7, 2.3, .................0.0, 0.0
```

Here in the first column contains the year and from the second column amount of rainfall in days of year.

Now I want to do precipitation analysis in R. How can I prepare time-series data from this data structure to perform time series analysis in R?

Thank you so much for your support in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this `dummy` data.

```
dummy <- tibble::tribble(
  ~year,     ~"1",          ~"2",   ~"3", 
  "2016",  1.25,        0.25, 0.25,
  "2017",  1.20,        0.20, 0.20,
  "2018",  1.30,        0.30, 0.30,
  "2019",  1.18,        0.18, 0.18,
)

  year    `1`   `2`   `3`
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2016   1.25  0.25  0.25
2 2017   1.2   0.2   0.2 
3 2018   1.3   0.3   0.3 
4 2019   1.18  0.18  0.18
```

then

```
melt(dummy) %>% mutate(variable = as.numeric(variable)) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(variable-1, origin = paste0(year, "-01-01"))) %>%
  select(date, value) %>% arrange(date)
```

become

```
         date value
1  2016-01-01  1.25
2  2016-01-02  0.25
3  2016-01-03  0.25
4  2017-01-01  1.20
5  2017-01-02  0.20
6  2017-01-03  0.20
7  2018-01-01  1.30
8  2018-01-02  0.30
9  2018-01-03  0.30
10 2019-01-01  1.18
11 2019-01-02  0.18
12 2019-01-03  0.18
```

#Additional code for your data

```
dummy <- read.table("D:/Rainfall.txt", header = TRUE)
colnames(dummy) <- as.character(c("Year",1:366))
melt(dummy, id.var="Year") %>% 
  mutate(variable = as.numeric(variable), value = as.numeric(str_replace(value, ",", ""))) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(variable-1, origin = paste0(Year, "-01-01"))) %>%
  select(date, value) %>% arrange(date)
```

`head` of result is like

```
        date value
1 1981-01-01   1.0
2 1981-01-02   0.0
3 1981-01-03   0.0
4 1981-01-04   0.0
5 1981-01-05   0.0
6 1981-01-06   0.9
```

Comment: Thank you @Park for your quick reply. I tried your suggestion but it does not work perfectly on my data set. I think it's due to the structure of my original data and dummy data that you prepared. As I have uploaded the original data on dropbox and here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/amy49ky2thrucsz/Rainfall.txt?dl=0. Could you please suggest the modification on the script to work my data. Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: @Amrit I'll try with your data and reply again. Thank you.